# Docker unable to connect AWS EC2 cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, spring-boot, devops

Hi I am able to deploy my spring boot application in my local docker container(1.11.2) in Windows-7.I followed the below steps to run the docker image in AWS EC2(Free Account:eu-central-1) but getting error

**Step 1**

Generated Amazon "AccessKeyID" and "SecretKey".

**Step 2**

Created new repository and it shows 5 Steps to push my docker image in AWS EC2.

**Step 3**

Installed Amazon CLI and run "aws configure" and configured all the details.
While running **aws iam list-users --output table** it shows all the user list

**Step 4**

Run the following command in Docker Container **aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2**

It returns the docker login.
While running the docker login it returns the following error :

```
XXXX@XXXX MINGW64 ~
$ docker login -u AWS -p <accessKey>/<secretKey>
Uwg
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized:
incorrect username or password

XXXX@XXXX MINGW64 ~
$ gLBBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggKyMIICrgIBADCCAqcGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQME8
Zei
bash: gLBBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggKyMIICrgIBADCCAqcGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQ
ME8Zei: command not found

XXXX@XXXX MINGW64 ~
$ lJnpBND9CwzAgEQgIICeLBms72Gl3TeabEXDx+YkK9ZlbyGxPmsuVI/rq81tDeIC68e0Ma+ghg3Dt
Bus
bash: lJnpBND9CwzAgEQgIICeLBms72Gl3TeabEXDx+YkK9ZlbyGxPmsuVI/rq81tDeIC68e0Ma+ghg
3DtBus: No such file or directory
```

I didn't get proper answer in google.It would be great if some one guide me to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never publish secret access keys from Amazon on any repo or pages that can be publicly available. I'm removing the keys on your post, but my recommendation is for you to reset them and get new ones, as your account could get compromised.

Comment: The secret keys are still in the edit log. Revoke those keys immediately OP.

Comment: Thank you let me revoke the keys now.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is not pointing to your ECR endpoint, but to DockerHub. Using Linux, normally I would simply run:

```
$ eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2)
```

This is possible because the `get-login` command is a wrapper that retrieves a new authorization token and formats the `docker login` command. You only need to execute the formatted command (in this case with `eval`)

But if you really want to run the `docker login` manually, you'll have to specify the authorization token and the endpoint of your repository:

```
$ docker login -u AWS -p <password> -e none https://<aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

Where `<password>` is actually the authorization token (which can be generated by the `aws ecr get-authorization-token` command).

Please refer to the documentation for more details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/index.html

Comment: Schroder Thank you for your quick response.while running the following command in docker "$ eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-1)" It shows Login succeeded but while pushing my image it shows "no basic auth credentials". So it's really Login is succeeded?Why it asks for basic auth?

Comment: I am using the following command to push "docker push <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/sample/sample-app:latest"

Comment: while running the following command in Docker container eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2) it shows login succeeded but while running in "git bash" it throws following error Warning: '-e' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. **See usage.
An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.23/auth: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.** since i am using windows i don't have terminal.Your help should be appreciable.

Comment: Well, I don't know if I can help you because I don't use Windows since ages... If it tells you "login successful", so from the Docker Daemon and AWS perspective everything is ok. I would check carefully the syntax and search for any Windows specific detail. BTW, you certainly know that `<aws_account_id>` and `<region>` are only placeholders, right? Also check if you placed the correct tag on your image. Good luck!

Comment: **"docker images"** show my image and the tag name."<aws_account_id>" and "<region>" are the only placeholders.It shows login successful in the docker container but while running the same command in windows cmd line or git bash it shows the following error **See usage. An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.23/auth: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.**.So i don't think connection is established to AWS

Comment: My docker is running in Virtual box that might create any issue?